# Heads and tails counter

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert, var

I am trying to create a heads or tails system in javascript.
I am stuck on it trying to keep scour however

So far I have:

```
prompt("Heads or tails")
var arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];

arr["Result"] = "heads";
var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr["Result"] === "heads")
    headCount += arr[i];`
`    else
    tailCount += arr[i];

alert("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Can you briefly explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish? You want to get a text from user input and compare it to what? And what is `arr["Result"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are mixing some logic up.

```
var arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
```

I assume that 0 means heads and one means tails?

```
arr["Result"] = "heads";
```

This will change the property `Result` on the object `arr` to be equal to the string "heads", and is probably not necessary.

```js
let arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];

let headCount = 0,
  tailCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === 0)
    headCount += 1;
  else
    tailCount += 1;
}

console.log("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
```

This will iterate over the array and increment one of the counting variables based on the value of the array at that index.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Eric H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635186/5157454), you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to easily get the same result:

```js
const arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];

const [headCount, tailCount] = arr.reduce((r, n) => {
  r[n] += 1;
  
  return r;
}, [0, 0]);


console.log("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];

let headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

arr.forEach(value => value ? headCount+=1 : tailCount+=1)

console.log(
  `HeadCount: ${headCount}  
TailCount: ${tailCount}`)
```